# How do I move the location of an animation through all keyframes without moving the original rig?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, armature

I have been through so much pain trying to figure out how to move my animation down without affecting the position of the actual rig when out of the animation, I can explain what I mean (if it helps this is made off of a bone rig).

So I have multiple animations on this one rig but since the root of the rig hasn't been moved while animated it makes the animation float if it's smaller than the height of the rig, example:

This is the rig with the animation -

[image: Animation on the rig]

This is the rig without an animation -

[image: No animation on the rig]

So if you look at the position of the rig's feet from the one without an animation and the one with an animation they are not aligned which makes it float when imported onto a place, I've tried adding a location keyframe to match it's axis but it leads to the same issue and I've tried looking for any other forums to find any solutions but they are not the same issue. I am a blender newbie so it's probably a simple solution.

Any help is much obliged!

Comment: You can add the location keyframe to the root bone not to the whole armature. Or you can find the Z axis of the root bone in the graph editor and adjust the whole animation's location there. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/index.html

Comment: Yeah i've found the solution thanks for the help anyways!